# Difference between [datatype] and [datatype[]]

Tags: powershell, variables, types, formatting

When casting a datatype for a variable, what does the extra empty square brackets do?

For example, in defining a parameter for a function, I have noticed these two ways of casting a data type for that parameter:

```
param(
    [string]$computername
)
```

vs:

```
param(
    [string[]]$computername
)
```

What purpose does the empty square brackets in the second example serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter in the second example accepts a list of strings (an array), the parameter in the first example only a single string.

This works in both cases:

```
-computername 'foo'
```

This works just in the second case:

```
-computername 'foo', 'bar'
```

Comment: Nice, So follow up question: Whats the difference between [array] and [string[]]?  I assume [array] can contain multiple types of data?

Comment: Correct. `[string[]]` is an array of strings, `[array]` is an array with no particular element type.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` denotes an array. So `[string[]]$computername` would denote a string array of computername's.